# How to show icons in $cordovaActionSheet plugin buttonLabels in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add icon in buttonLabels in [$cordovaActionSheet plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/actionSheet/) but it didn't working.  I have tried

```
var options = {
            title: 'Share',
            buttonLabels: ['<i class="ion-social-facebook"></i> Share via Facebook', '<i class="ion-social-twitter"></i> Share via Twitter'],
        };
```

but it prints tag as it is. How do I show icons in button labels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have tagged `ionic-framework` as well. If you are using `Ionic` you can make use of `$ionicActionSheet` instead of the `$cordovaActionSheet`. See [this doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/).

With the `$ionicActionSheet` it is no problem adding images:

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller(function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, $timeout) {

 // Triggered on a button click, or some other target
 $scope.show = function() {

   // Show the action sheet
   var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
     buttons: [
       { text: '<i class="ion-social-facebook"></i> Share via Facebook' },
       { text: '<b>Share</b> This' },
       { text: 'Move' }
     ],
     destructiveText: 'Delete',
     titleText: 'Modify your album',
     cancelText: 'Cancel',
     cancel: function() {
      // add cancel code..
    },
     buttonClicked: function(index) {
       return true;
     }
   });

   // For example's sake, hide the sheet after two seconds
   $timeout(function() {
     hideSheet();
   }, 2000);

 };
});
```